# The response received in javascript is not XML while on browser it displays an XML

Tags: javascript, xml, rest

I am new to javascript and REST services. I am trying to fetch some data from a url. The javascript code I wrote is as below:-

```js
<script>
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://findtest.akamai.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27Agora%27&sourceid=%2782cdf98b-cc8b-48c3-a706-d88c1333cc4b%27&QueryTemplatePropertiesUrl=%27spfile://webroot/queryparametertemplate.xml%27&rowlimit=60&selectproperties=%27Title,Author,Url,Date%27&StartRow=%270%27&trimduplicates=%27true%27", false);
request.send();
var xml = request.responseText;
document.write(xml);
</script>
```

The responseText received looks something like below:-
[image]

While when I open it in browser IE/Chrome:-
This same response flashes on the screen for a moment and then proper XML is displayed like below:-
[image]

I am unable to get the response XML in my javascript. Is it some kind of encoding that I have to decode ? I want the proper XML response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that when writing to an HTML page, you're writing **HTML**, not plain text. `<` and `&` (at a minimum) have to be encoded as entities.

`document.write` has virtually no place in 2018 (or really the 21st century at all). You can instead append a text node so the string is used as text, not HTML:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xml));
```

Example:

```js
var xml = "<root><thing/><another-thing/></root>";
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xml));
```

You might even wrap it in a `code` element:

```
var code = document.createElement("code");
code.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xml));
document.body.appendChild(code);
```

Example:

```js
var xml = "<root><thing/><another-thing/></root>";
var code = document.createElement("code");
code.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xml));
document.body.appendChild(code);
```

Comment: Thanks Crowder. Works for me.